# Can jQuery .hasClass() choose pseudo selectors?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

let's say I want to add an action based if this div is the 3rd child in the row, can I put `.hasClass('column:nth-child(3)')` and it will work?

Comment: You should create a [`http://codepen.io/`](CodePen) or [`https://jsfiddle.net/`](JsFiddle) to attempt it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.is` for that.

```
$element.is(":nth-child(3)"); // Will return boolean value
```

Reference: [.is](http://api.jquery.com/is/)